# Why does Html.BeginForm needs to be wrapped inside curly braces?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Why does begin form needs to be wrapped inside curly braces like this:

```
@{Html.BeginForm();}
    // some other stuff....
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" />
@{ Html.EndForm();}
```

Vs. if I just want a label I can simply do :

```
@Html.Label("Hi")
```

When I tried `@Html.BeginForm()` with out the curly braces I simply get

> System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm

printed on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an explanation from remarks section of [`BeginForm`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx) reference (emphasis mine):

> The `BeginForm` method renders a form that will be handled by a
>   controller action method.
>
> **You can use this method in a using block. In that case, the method
>   renders the closing `</form>` tag at the end of the using block.**

If you call `@Html.BeginForm()` method without code block or `using` block, it treated as standard Razor expression (HTML encoded) and implicitly calls `ToString()` method, hence the type name `System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm` will shown instead of opening `<form>` tag.

When `BeginForm` used inside `using` block, it renders both opening `<form>` and closing `</form>` tag in HTML output, hence this `using` block:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" />
}
```

will transformed to HTML output like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" />
</form>
```

Note that `Html.BeginForm` returns `IDisposable` object which automatically calls `Html.EndForm()` on disposal, hence no need to use [`Html.EndForm()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.endform(v=vs.118).aspx) after `using` block.

*Second*, [`@Html.Label(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.labelextensions.label(v=vs.118).aspx) helper not requires code block because it derived from `System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper` namespace that returns `MvcHtmlString`, which renders both `<label>` and `</label>` tag simultaneously.

As a side note, if you trying to use `@Html.EndForm()` outside code block (wrapped with `@{ ... }`), this exception will thrown because `Html.EndForm` is a `void` method which `Write(void)` turns into compile-time error:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)'
>   has some invalid arguments.

Additional reference:

[Razor Syntax Quick Reference](https://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/)

Comment: I always forget the `using`

Answer (score 2):

> Razor compound @using - in C#, a using statement is used to ensure an
>   object is disposed. In Razor, the same mechanism is used to create
>   HTML Helpers that contain additional content.

Here is a good [Razor syntax reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-2.0#compound-) article that goes into more detail, including the syntax for `@using (Html.BeginForm())`

Answer (score 1):

The @Html.BeginForm Writes an opening  tag to the response, and the @Html.Label it's a method that returns an HTML label element and dont need to open and close braces.

You dont need to use Begin and End.

You could use like that:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
     // some other stuff....
     <input type="submit" name="Submit" />
  }
```

The braces of @using will do the Html.EndForm for you.

Comment: yes.. but still doesn't understand why the curly braces for beginForm but not for label... whats the diff there?..

Comment: `Html.Label` is an method that has this signature: 
`MvcHtmlString Label(string expression, string labelText, object htmlAttributes)`, so you dont need braces.  

`Html.BeginForm()` is used inside an `@usign`, and using uses braces.

I will update my awnser